# C# process start focus issue

Tags: c#, process, focus

When I start a new process, it automatically gets the focus. how can I prevent it from getting the focus or instead get back the focus to my application?

here is the code I'm using:

```
string path = @"c:\temp\myprocess.exe";  
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(path);  
info.WorkingDirectory = path;  
Process p = Process.Start(info);
```

I just need the executed process not to get the focus.

Thank you very much,
Adi Barda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you do

```
myForm.Focus();
```

where myForm is the form on your main application

Comment: It does not work because at the moment you start the thread there is a delay until its UI is shown. By that time you already call Focus on your form but the external process still comes last and steals focus.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer!? It does not answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe setting the [WindowStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle.aspx) property to [Minimized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle.aspx) can help.

Comment: I think it still takes focus, even though it's not displayed

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to show the process at all, try this:

```
string path = @"c:\temp\myprocess.exe";
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
info.WorkingDirectory = path;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Or set WindowStyle to ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized if you want it visible but minimized, as Uwe Keim said.

Answer (score 0):

What i´ve done was to wait a little delay until the other application was succesfully loaded, then focus my application window.

```
//Test window
const string strCmdText = "/C cd C:\\sqlcipher";
Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);

//Delay
int liMilliseconds = 50;
Thread.Sleep(liMilliseconds);

//Code to bring window to front
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
this.Show();
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```